# When is a function of an ergodic stationary process itself ergodic stationary?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, convergence, law-of-large-numbers

I am working with a function which has the form $f(X_1, \dots, X_n)$, where $\\{X_n\\}$ is an ergodic stationary process. Theorem 5.6 in ["A first course in stochastic processes" by Karlin & Taylor](http://webdelprofesor.ula.ve/economia/drivas/materias/ProcesosEstocasticos/Libros/A%20first%20course%20in%20stochastics%20Processes%20%5BSamuel%20Karlin,%20Howard%20M.Taylor%5D.pdf) states a list of conditions which are equivalent to ergodicity, one of which is that the limit
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n f(X_j, X_{j+1}, \dots) = \mathbf{E}[f(X_0, X_1, \dots)]
\end{equation}
is satisfied for any function $f$, if the expectation exists.
However, this function seems to take infinitely long inputs in the "wrong direction", which I guess means it doesn't apply to my case. Do there exist similar results, or conditions which enable applying this result, for the case when $f$ is a function of all *past* observations?

*Edit:* I am sorry I wasn't sufficiently precise.

I am indeed referring to a sequence of functions. In my mind I had something like the operation $f(X_1, \dots, X_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n c^{n-i} X_i$, where $0 < c  < 1$. It seems to me that in such a case, the dependence on the past should decay sufficiently fast for the sequence $\{ f(X_1, \dots, X_n) \}$ itself to be ergodic, such that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n f(X_1, \dots, X_j) = \mathbf{E}[f(X_0, X_1, \dots)]
\end{equation}
where we would define $f(X_0, X_1, \dots)$ to be the limit of the sequence $\{ f(X_1, \dots, X_n) \}$, such that this statement makes sense. Such a result seems to apply to for the particular example of a geomatrically weighted sum at least, but I wonder if a result exist for more general mappings.

At the face of it, this looks very similar to the result I referred to. However, the result instead seems to refer to operations like $f(X_j, X_{j+1}, \dots) = \sum_{i=j}^{\infty} c^i X_i$. Instead of depending on the finite but increasing-in-length sequence $X_1, \dots, X_n$, the function $f$ depends on the infinite sequence $X_j, X_{j+1}, \dots$. This is what I meant by it working in the "wrong" direction.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "in the wrong direction" and tell us the sense in which it doesn't apply in your case.  The reason I ask is that at the outset you do not describe a "function:" you are describing a *sequence* of functions indexed by $n.$

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I have attempted clarifying the question now.

Comment: It looks like ordinarily $\{ f(X_1, \dots, X_n) \}$ doesn't even have a limit.  And it's certainly not stationary: its variance changes with $n.$